# Q: Age discrimintation?

Tags: employment, discrimination, age

Q: Age discrimination?
Can a federal employer post a job opening without mentioning anything about age requirement (between the ages of X-Y at the start of the position)? Adding equal opportunity employer at the end of the job opening.
Yet, send an applicant an email asking if the individual will be between the ages of 18-30 years old at the start of the position?
Thoughts, please?
Thank you.

Comment: It's possible. I've seen job openings for...I don't remember the wording but for something like recent graduates.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: The nature of the position might matter. For example, a military position has a somewhat similar age restriction and there are some statutory age restrictions for certain kinds of positions.

Comment: ohwilleke, Thank you for your feedback. Maybe so, but why is that not posted for everyone to see when applying? I just found that strange to only address in an individual email.

Comment: If your question is in regard to a specific country, please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the US, the [Age Discrimination in Employment Act](https://www.eeoc.gov/age-discrimination) forbids age discrimination against employees who are 40 or older, therefore discrimination against those under 40 is legal. In Canada, you would have to specify the province – [in Ontario](https://www.ohrc.on.ca/en/age-discrimination-brochure), age discrimination for those over 18 is illegal. Likewise, age discrimination is illegal in [Norway](http://www.agediscrimination.info/international-age-discrimination/norway). In the US, it is generally illegal to ask a question that probed into an absolutely protected matter, such as race or pregnancy, and it is legal to ask a candidate's age. [In Ontario](https://www.kcyatlaw.ca/illegal-interview-questions/), it would be illegal to ask the question.

Comment: "therefore discrimination against those under 40 is legal": except in states that prohibit age discrimination and don't have an exception for people under 40.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @phoog in which case discrimination against *underage* people still is legal: you can ask the question if they were born on or before (date 18 years ago) and or if you have to comply with child labor laws, and deny their application based on *that*